# how to read SetEnv in PHP when calling from the command line?

Tags: php, apache, environment-variables, command-line-interface

What I like about Apache `.conf` files, and what is commonly used obviously is the `SetEnv` command.  However, when I run `php artisan do:something` from the command line, this same access to the .conf file appears to not be available (after all there is no "domain" or "website" understood from the command line).

In short, what is an alternate way to either read the same `.conf` file for the envvar's (ideal) or read from some file outside my codebase to differentiate environment (not ideal but certainly OK)?

Comment: I guess laravel has `.env` file that could be accessible from any environments. Why not to keep common variables there?

Comment: Well, I'd want to keep the file outside the application so that the code itself is agnostic to the environment, or more specifically doesn't specify it.

Comment: can You share `.conf` file structure?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.htaccess` [parser](https://github.com/tivie/php-htaccess-parser) when running Your app.

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

if(php_sapi_name() === 'cli') {
  $file = new \SplFileObject(__DIR__.'/.htaccess');
  $parser = new \Tivie\HtaccessParser\Parser();
  $htaccess = $parser->parse(null, IGNORE_WHITELINES|IGNORE_COMMENTS);

  foreach($htaccess AS $line) {
    if($line->getName() == 'SetEnv') {
      putenv($line->getArguments()[0], $line->getArguments()[1]);
    }
  }
}
```

Just FYI In modern containerized world it's better to use environment variables that passed on script invocation or in container image directives.

Let's say this is Your script (`test.php`):

```
<?php

if(getenv('PASSWORD') === 'blablabla') {
  // do something secret
  echo 'Psst... I have got a secret to share with You';
}
```

And execute it like:

```
PASSWORD=blablabla php test.php
```

how it looks in `Dockerfile` (part of it):

```
ENV MODE dev

CMD ['php', 'test.php']
```

and in php code:

```
if(getenv('MODE') == 'dev') {
  // enable logger, debugger and etc...
}
```

Comment: I will remember the Dockerfile idea for when I use Docker.  The problem with parsing the `.htaccess file` is that it's still in the code repo - so every environment is going to get the same value ;)